# Android Jsoup парсинг

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Подскажите в чем ошибка? вылетает приложение

```
public class ParceNews extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView list_view;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parce_news);

        list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        ParceTitle parceTitle = new ParceTitle();
        parceTitle.execute();

        try {
            final HashMap<String,String> hashMap = parceTitle.get();
            final ArrayList<String>arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Map.Entry entry : hashMap.entrySet()){
                arrayList.add(entry.getKey().toString());
            }
            final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ParceNews.this
                    ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

            list_view.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    ParceText parceText = new ParceText();
                    parceText.execute(hashMap.get(arrayList.get(position)));

                    try {
                        list_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        textView.setText(parceText.get());
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        list_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class ParceText extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String str = " ";
            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                Element element = document.select(".itemFullText").first();
                str = element.text();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return str;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class ParceTitle extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String, String>>{

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ndu.edu.ua/index.php/ua/vsi-novuni").get();
                Elements elements = document.select(".catItemTitle");
                for(Element element:elements){
                    Element element1 = element.select("a[href]").first();
                    hashMap.put(element.text(), element1.attr("abs:href"));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Когда у вас происходит ошибка - она отображается в логах вместе со строкой возникновения. Имея логи решить проблемы -  дело несколких секунд. Без логов же её решить почти невозможно, т.к. мало у кого есть время на компилирование и запуск вашего кода.

Comment: спасибо, там просто много чего написано и не совсем ясно как выбрать именно нужное для решения

Comment: Логи ошибок выделены красным. Обычно в начале идёт тип ошибки. Далее синим подсвечены кликабельно строки где ошибка возникает. В 95% случаев тип ошибки - `NullPointerException`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Set java.util.HashMap.entrySet()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at katka.application.com.katka.ParceNews.onCreate(ParceNews.java:43)

вот судя по всему эта ошибка

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос, явно и однозначно указав что за 43 строка. И не используйте так `AsyncTask` - при медленном интернете приложение зависнет и умрёт. Никогда не используйте `get` у таска - это максимально неправильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы в своей задаче, распарсив данные в `Map` не возвращаете их, а возвращаете `null` - оттого и получаете `NPE`